# Column cannot be found or is not specified for query - Progress SQL Interface

Tags: sql, openedge

I get the following error, I haven't had this issue before and was wondering if `lvscat` is an alias for something. From what I read that is a common issue, but even if it is that I am still unsure of how to fix it. This is the full Error

```
[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Column "LVSCAT" cannot be found or is not specified for query.
```

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO PUB.lvsbk (BookingNo, LvsCat)
VALUES (1007265, 'G')
```

Mapping with SQL Interface:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps that ell is actually an eye?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the column was defined as `"lvsCat"`.  That means that the case is important.

Unfortunately, you have to use the double quotes to reference it:

```
INSERT INTO PUB.lvsbk (BookingNo, "LvsCat")
    VALUES (1007265, 'G') ;
```

If this is the case, you might want to recreate the table without escaping the name of identifiers.

Comment: Case is not the issue unfortunately. Copying the name exactly gives me the same error.

Comment: @user15119845 . . . You have to use the double quotes.

Comment: still not the issue, not required for the OpenEdge SQL. I had found the issue. Was because the property, actually just didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what tool you are using to demonstrate the definition of your table, but you can view the *actual* definition of your table with:

```
select * from sysprogress.syscolumns where tbl = 'lvsbk';
```

Alternatively a simple:

```
select top 1 * from pub.lvsbk;
```

May provide enough evidence as to what your column is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was because the field simply didn't exist.